# PHP MySQL select a specific/non-specific pattern

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have this piece of data set in a MySQL table in 2 columns (ID => textStr) as follows:

> 1=>"A~b#c#d~e~f~g", 2=>"Abcdefg", 3=>"Ab~cd~ef~g#", 4=>"A~bcde~f#g~"

Let's call the ~ and # needless characters (NC).

How can I achieve the following:
If a user searches for "abcdefg", the query will return all the 4 records in myTable because they all contain the same letters in the same order regardless of the NCs. However, if the user searches for the same string specifying one of the NCs, the query will return the string that contains the same letters having the same NC in the same position as in the search.
For example, if they search for "A~bcdefg", the query will return the 1st and 4th records as they both have the same letters and ~ after the letter A.

A starting point:

```
select * from myTable where textStr="A~bcdefg"
```

This query obviously returns 0 records.

Comment: Probably something like `WHERE textStr LIKE 'A%b%c%d%e%f%g'` The `%` is a wildcard matching 0 or more characters, adjust to your needs.  Then there's Regular Expressions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: If you clarify and add more detail we can help.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, I'm not sure the % would help, as it could be replaced by a different letter as well, e.g. Axbcdefg. Actually, I'm trying to tolerate specific chars in the search, but not letters.

Comment: And regarding the Regular Expressions, I tried a lot, but I couldn't work out a pattern. I also don't know the exact length of each string in the data set.